# Tamagawa number conjecture

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

I heard somewhere that the above formulation of conjecture is for predicting the exact leading term of a L-function at an integer. 
But i didnt find any reference about how it is stated,
anyone please give me any reference or either state the conjecture precisely ,thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'Tamagawa Number Conjecture' is a bit murky. When I hear it, I think of two different things: the Bloch-Kato Conjecture, or the Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer Conjecture.

The Block-Kato Conjecture is badly named, because there are a couple different BK Conjectures on very different topics. So I have heard the one we are thinking of as the Tamagawa Number Conjecture because it deals with Tamagawa Numbers. More on this can be read, for instance, [here](http://andromeda.rutgers.edu/~liguo/psfiles/repmrl.pdf).

The Swinnerton-Dyer Conjecture is one of the Millenium Prize problems, so lots can be read about it. But for the sake of completeness, I refer you to its [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birch%E2%80%93Swinnerton-Dyer_conjecture) and to this [description by Andrew Wiles](http://www.claymath.org/millennium/Birch_and_Swinnerton-Dyer_Conjecture/birchswin.pdf), at the Clay Institute's site. Look in particular at the first 'conjecture' of Wiles's summary.

For a general overview of the related ideas going into this conjecture, I recommend reading this [abstract](http://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/Seminars/Kuwait/abstracts/L56.pdf), or a copy of the lecture itself if you can find it (maybe not so unlikely, as Cambridge is good about those things).

Comment: You are right, the "Block-Kato conjecture" is badly named ;)

Comment: @mixed math:but what is the Difference between both of them ,i mean BSD and Tamagawa number conjecture